# How to reference another worksheet in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So I need to lock my excel formula columns for a task I am doing at work. And to do that I need to make the formulas automated so that it wont have to be edited in the future.

So, basically what the formula is doing is its referencing a different worksheet within the workbook and taking a column of the referenced worksheet and calculating the value using that range.

Formula: COUNTIF('A1 worksheet'!A2:A20,">.10")

So, what I want to do is reference the name 'A1 worksheet' with value in some other cell like suppose cell B2 is in 'formula' worksheet and it contains the value 'A1 worksheet', I tried doing COUNTIF('B2'!A2:A20,">.10") but it gave me error. Is there a workaround to this formula so that I can make the Formula automated and not having the add name of new worksheet in the formula every time?

This is my first question here. So if I did the poor job of explaining it please let me know.

Thank you!

Comment: Look up `INDIRECT`.

Comment: In cell `C2` of the `formula` worksheet you could use `=COUNTIF(INDIRECT("'"&B2&"'"&"!A2:A20"),">.1")`.

Comment: Oh my god your guys, thank you so much. Even though the answer to this was simple. It was a great time saver for this noob. Thank you both of you!